# Create custom buckets for df based on column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to add a new column with custom buckets (see example below)based on the price values in the price column.

- `< 400 = low`
- `>=401 and <=1000 = medium`
- `>1000 = expensive`

Table

```
product_id  price 

     2       1203       
     4        500      
     5        490       
     6        200      
     3        429       
     5        321
```

**Output table**

```
product_id  price   price_category 
 
     2       1001   high    
     4        500   medium   
     5        490   medium  
     6        200   low 
     3        429   medium  
     5        321   low
```

This what I have tried so far:

```
from numba import njit

def cut(arr):
    bins = np.empty(arr.shape[0])
    for idx, x in enumerate(arr):
        if (x >= 0) & (x <= 50):
            bins[idx] = 1
        elif (x >= 51) & (x <= 100):
            bins[idx] = 2
        elif (x >= 101) & (x <= 250):
            bins[idx] = 3
        elif (x >= 251) & (x <= 1000):
            bins[idx] = 4
        else:
            bins[idx] = 5

    return bins

a = cut(df2['average_listings'].to_numpy())

conversion_dict = {1: 'S',
                   2: 'M',
                   3: 'L',
                   4: 'XL',
                   5: 'XXL'}

bins = list(map(conversion_dict.get, a))
```

**--> But I am struggling to add this to the main df**

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want a place to start, search for how to use `apply` with dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conditions = [
    df['price'].lt(400), 
    df['price'].ge(401) & df['price'].le(1000), 
    df['price'].gt(1000)]

choices = ['low', 'medium', 'high']

df['price_category'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

---

```
# print(df)
   product_id  price price_category
0           2   1203           high
1           4    500         medium
2           5    490         medium
3           6    200            low
4           3    429         medium
5           5    321            low
```

Answer (score 5):

`pandas` has it's own [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) method. Specify the right bin edges and the corresponding labels.

```
df['price_category'] = pd.cut(df.price, [-np.inf, 400, 1000, np.inf],
                              labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])

   product_id  price price_category
0           2   1203           high
1           4    500         medium
2           5    490         medium
3           6    200            low
4           3    429         medium
5           5    321            low
```

---

Without the `labels` argument, you get back the exact bins (and closure, right by default) used for the data, which in this case are:

```
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(-inf, 400.0] < (400.0, 1000.0] < (1000.0, inf]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
df.loc[df.price < 400, 'price_category'] = 'low'
```

Comment: This is not helpful at all